# Draw Shaded Area on Google Map V3 - Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[Map Shaded http://demo.silkea.com/map_shade.png](http://demo.silkea.com/map_shade.png)

I am trying to accomplish drawing a referenced area for example. Just shaded, static, no further user inputs or changes.

Trying to accomplish with Javascript and Google Map V3 - can find examples of of drawing dynamically but not static.

Any help appreciated

---

Got her... Here it is for others...
Thx for suggestions...

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function initialize() {
 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.176630373, -114.47321937);
 var myOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
  center: myLatLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
 };

 var mapsquare;

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

 var squareCoords = [
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.179858807660786, -114.47836921691896),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.173563152178794, -114.47836921691896),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.173563152178794, -114.46892784118654),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.179858807660786, -114.46892784118654)
];

 // Construct the polygon
 mapsquare = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: squareCoords,
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 1,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35
 });

 mapsquare.setMap(map);
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">

 <br><br>


 NW Marker <br>
 51.179858807660786  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  -114.47836921691896
 <br><br>
 SE Marker<br>
 51.173563152178794 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   -114.46892784118654
 <br><br>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 850px; height: 450px;"></div>



 <br><br>


 <br><br>
 </body>
```

Comment: Glad to help. If you believe my answer below addressed your question, it's customary to click the arrow shape next to the answer to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like an [InfoBox](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBox) will do what you need; it functions similar to a label on the map. Or, if you need something that will allow you to exactly define the corners at specific coordinates, you could try a [google.maps.Rectangle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Rectangle).

---

***Follow up Edit:***

The problem in your code is that 2 of the coordinates are out of order, so the shape is getting twisted to follow the coordinates. If you take the existing shape coordinates:

```
var squareCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.179858807660786, -114.47836921691896),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.173563152178794, -114.47836921691896),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.179858807660786, -114.46892784118654),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.173563152178794, -114.46892784118654)
];
```

And just reverse the order of the last two points, you will get:

```
var squareCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.179858807660786, -114.47836921691896),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.173563152178794, -114.47836921691896),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.173563152178794, -114.46892784118654),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.179858807660786, -114.46892784118654)

];
```

And this will work fine. Here is an image of the map I get running a local unit test:
[image]

Comment: Yeah I need to define the corner coordinates... I'll look into Rectangle

Comment: Little stuck... Not drawing square - drawing two rectangles - [link](http://demo.silkea.com/gps.htm)

Comment: Looks like you have a corner flipped. It's twisting itself to fit the coordinates. Taking a deeper look. If you just switch the order of the last 2 points in the square, I think you will be good. Still looking deeper -

Comment: Check my edit to my answer above - just have to switch the order of 2 of the points and you are good to go. Just a minor adjustment :)

Comment: Thx Sean u pointed it out... Had to go NW corner, SW Corner, SE Corner, NE Corner - my original question has the right coding as well - modified from Google Map V3 API

Comment: Yep, looks great after that. Glad to have helped -